# mysql: how to copy database and required dependencies

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I need to set up an automated copy of a single mysql database (not the whole DBMS). If I use mysqldump to dump and recreate a DB, the copy may be unusable because the user accounts need to also be copied. Triggers in the source DB for instance may be copied, but there's no guarantee that they will execute correctly in the new DB because the original triggers were designed to run as some particular user.

A couple of questions:

- how can I automate copying of the user accounts and permissions?
- is there a way, when copying a db to check whether all of its dependencies are met? (E.g. are all of the databases referred to by the stored procedures present?)

I understand that I can replicate the whole DBMS - this is overkill (and often not practical for hourly regressions)

Comment: You can use this PHP tool
https://github.com/lazada-com/database_minifier
You can find documentation here https://github.com/lazada-com/database_minifier/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Users and grants are stored in the `mysql` database, so you could insert rows directly. MySQL Workbench includes the [mysqluserclone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqluserclone.html) utility, which provides a safer way to copy user accounts and permissions from one server to another.

I don't know of any direct way to check dependencies, but [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) contains all the necessary metadata. Other utilities from MySQL Workbench such as [mysqldiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldiff.html) and [mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html) would probably help in determining when something is missing.

Comment: Thanks -- I need to hook it up to an automation system. Can MySQL Workbench be used from the command-line on machines with and xserver?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is largely a GUI tool; it used to be bundled with the CLI utilities but they are now a separate download called MySQL Utilities: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities